# Merging unassociated array with serialized name/value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Other than just iterating over the unassociated array and manually adding them, how does one merge an unassociated array with serialized name/value pairs?

```
//I select some values
var data = $('#mytable input:checked');
console.log(data);  //Object[input attribute value = "1", input attribute value = "3"]

//I get some extra values I wish to send to the server
var types = data.map(function() {
    return $(this).data("types");
}).get();
console.log(types); // ["type1", "type3"]

//I serialize data
data = data.serializeArray();
console.log(data);  // [Object { name="id[]",  value="1"}, Object { name="id[]",  value="3"}]

//I add an extra value
data.push({
    name: "task",
    value: 'restoreRecord'
})
console.log(data);  // [Object { name="id[]",  value="1"}, Object { name="id[]",  value="3"}, Object { name="task",  value="restoreRecord"}]

/*
How do I merge data and types so that I come up with the following:
[
Object { name="id[]",    value="1"},
Object { name="id[]",    value="3"},
Object { name="types[]", value="type1"},
Opject { name="types[]", value="type3"},
Object { name="task",    value="restoreRecord"}
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a for loop over `types` and add values from it to `data`

```
// I want to merge this
var data = [{
    name: "id[]",
    value: "1"
}, {
    name: "id[]",
    value: "3"
}, {
    name: "task",
    value: "restoreRecord"
}];

// with this
var types = ['type1', 'type2'];

for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
    data.push({
        name: 'types[]',
        value: types[i]
    });
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I was in the process of stating without the loop right when you answered.

Comment: Didn't know if there was some sort of baked in jQuery way of doing so.